# Почему Андройд эмулятор все скачиваемые торрент файлы обрезает до 2 кб?

Tags: android-sdk, android, эмулятор

Я обнаружил что при в Android эмуляторе при загрузке торрент файлов их размер урезается до **2 килобайт**. Может быть кто-нибуть знает как можно решить данную проблему?

Такая ситуация у меня получается на **Android 2.3.3** и **4.0.3** в Ubuntu. Файлы скачивал с сайта [kat.ph](http://kat.ph)

P.S. Может быть таким образом Google борется с распространением нелецензионного контента, хотя вряд ли.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне кажется там его не стоит размещать так как биткод - это форум для пользователей компьютерной техники, а не эмуляторов. На физичесом андройд устройтсве нет такой проблемы.

Comment: тогда вот здесь http://android.stackexchange.com/ там он как раз к месту придется

Comment: а чем торренты качаются? может просто автор программы так сделал (ну мало чего он себе придумал).

Comment: сами торренты ничем не качаются, а торрент файл должен скачваться браузером